# How to do a PHP Batch request with Google Analytics

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, batching

I have to do 40 requests to Google Analytics at the same time. But I have problems to understand the following batching explanation of GA to PHP ([Link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/batching)). I understand the purpose, but how do I translate this to PHP? I have no problem to do a usual cURL request, but how would it look like, when several requests are "nested" in a top request, like here? Is this possible with cURL? I am still new to PHP.

Without batching it takes too long to execute every request.

```
$authorization= 'Authorization: Bearer '.$google->accessToken;

$batch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt_array($batch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: multipart/mixed' , $authorization),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,         
));

##...add nested requests here somewhere....

$result = curl_exec($batch);
curl_close($batch);
```

Google example:

> POST /batch HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: www.googleapis.com
>
> Content-length: 731
>
> Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_0123456789
>
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.5gFZooleNoSpGqYOOF0eFciUGz1x26k9GagZoW7HJCogWlCoNOotxlZPo7bDbwo1ykDq
>
> --batch_0123456789
>
> Content-Type: application/http
>
> Content-ID:
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> POST [https]://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXXXX/webproperties/UA-XXXXXX-1/customDimensions
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Content-Length: 68
>
> {
>    "name": "Campaign Group",
>    "scope": "SESSION",
>    "active": true
>   }
>
> --batch_0123456789
>
> Content-Type: application/http
>
> Content-ID:
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> POST [https]://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXXXX/webproperties/UA-XXXXXX-1/customDimensions
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Content-Length: 67
>
> {
>    "name": "Campaign Type",
>    "scope": "SESSION",
>    "active": true
>   }
>
> --batch_0123456789--

Comment: Even if you do not want to use the Google PHP client library you can look at the code (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Http/Batch.php) to see how Google does it (they use the Guzzle http client instead of pure Curl but I guess one could apply similar principles for Curl. Or simply use the Google libs).

Comment: [Client Library documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/batch) For those who want to go the easy route.

Comment: Link non-existing. In github, you can only find the reference, not a guide. https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-php-client/master/Google/Http/Batch.html. So, I guess no easy route in the end.

Comment: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-php-client/master/Google/Http/Batch.html  Just reference on GitHub.  No guide :(